# Can't play music downloaded from ubuntu on my android

Tags: 14.04, android, music, youtube-dl

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Android 2.3.5.
I tryed to download music from youtube with the youtube-dl -x  in the m4a format and mp3 with other applications, but then I can't play it on Android. I don't have problems doing it on Windows, it works fine there. I searched for an answer here and there and could not solve this problem.
What do I have to do here to make it work?

Comment: Which media player did you use?

Comment: It is the default music player. It is called "Música" that means "Music". I don't have much memory on Android to install a new music player, so I would like to solve it with this player.

Comment: Are u sure that your player can play these files. Some default media players will not have the codecs of certain file types. You may need to update them.

Comment: The music player is updated and I can play music with these formats if I download it on Windows.

Comment: Then it's better you try different music player or contact their customer support.